# Replace div with new div using jQuery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need a simple solution for replacing a div with a new div, cross-browser compatible using javascript or JQuery. I'll add some code below. Div "myDiv-B" needs to be replaced by a new div:

```
<div id="myDiv-C">{% include 'snippets/contactpaneel.rain' %}</div>
```

Here are my divs

```html
<div id="myDiv-A">
<div id="myDiv-B"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please search for your answer before you ask a question, read the [Help centre on how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: use-

    `$('#myDiv-A').html(yourcontent);`

and you myDiv-B will be replaced by

Comment: @Alexandru-Ionut Mihai, yes it is, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome, @Eddy.

Comment: @John Ambrose, thanks! Also a good option!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `.replaceWith()` method.

> `.replaceWith` method replace each element in the set of matched
>   elements.

```js
$('#myDiv-B').replaceWith('<div>Hello</div>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv-A">
<div id="myDiv-B"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have enough rep to mark as duplicate, no?